# Problem to set JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, environment-variables

In `~/.bash_profile` I set the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin
```

After saving and close I ran:

```
sudo su
source .bash_profile
```

`echo $PATH` brings

```
root@ubuntu:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin
```

`which java` is

```
/usr/bin/java
```

But if I start smartgit there's the following warning

```
ip@ubuntu:/usr/share/smartgithg/bin$ ./smartgithg.sh 
Warning: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java/bin/java does not exist
```

Why doesn't 'which java' point to the new java I installed?
And Why does contain $PATH `bin/java/` twice?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem?

Answer (score 7):

You can select java version using `update-alternatives` command.

Run below command in terminal.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And type selection number that you want to use.

Like this:

[image: selecting java version]

Caution: The above description is the procedures for changing a default version. It is not an answer of this question, but should help you set the JAVA home

Comment: Great, thank you. [wikihow.com](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Your-Java_Home-Path-in-Ubuntu) was a big help

Comment: MY javahome is still empty. sry but have to -1 this ... if I could

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses the `update-alternatives` system to manage which installation of the Java JDK or JRE should be used. This allows you to have multiple versions of Java installed, but still control which one is used by default.

This is why `which java` doesn't show the version you installed; `/usr/bin/java` is just a symlink. If you run `ls -l /usr/bin/java` you'll see something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jul  4  2013 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

and if you follow the trail by running `ls -l /etc/alternatives/java` you'll see something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jul 15  2013 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

but the exact path will depend on which version you have selected.

You can select which version of Java you want to run using this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Your path contains `bin/java` twice because you have configured `$JAVA_HOME` incorrectly. `$JAVA_HOME` should point at the root directory for your Java installation; in your case, `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/`. You were pointing it at the `java` binary itself.

You should not need to add `$JAVA_HOME` to your `$PATH` unless you are installing Java manually and not using `update-alternatives`, because `/usr/bin` is already in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrectly set your `JAVA_HOME` variable in your `~/.bash_profile` file. Change your `JAVA_HOME` variable to:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/
```

and then do `source ~/.bash_profile`

This should resolve your issue.